# PHP -CSV REading and Uploading images from url

Tags: php, import

Can any one help me to find out a code snippet in PHP to read contents in an CSV file and then insert to some tables as well as fetch some data from www(fetch image fom the image url in CSV file)

Answer (score 1):

The code would look something like this. Note this code hasn't been tested nor fortified for security.

$handle = fopen("fileUploads.csv", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
     $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO myTable values ('$data[0]', '$data[1]')";

```
  //run the sql

  //download the image
  $saveHandle = fopen("image".$data[0] .".jpg", "w+");

  $getImageHandle = fopen($data[1], "r"); // open the image

  $contents = stream_get_contents($getImageHandle); //download it

  fclose($getImageHandle); //close the handle

  fwrite($saveHandle, $contents); //write the contents to disk

  fclose($saveHandle); //close the handle
```

}

fclose($handle);

This code assumes your csv looks like this.

1,http://www.foobar.com/images/something.jpg